# How do I mock a static method using PowerMockito?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

I am using:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>${powermock.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

I am attempting to test a piece of code with the following call:

```java
final KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_PAIR_ALGORITHM, DEFAULT_PROVIDER);
```

The two constants are of type String, so I'm calling:

```java
java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(String algorithm, String provider)
```

I've tried:

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(KeyPairGenerator.class)
public class TestClass {

    private static final String DEFAULT_PROVIDER = "BC";
    private static final String KEY_PAIR_ALGORITHM = "RSA";

    @Test
    public void test() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
        final KeyPairGenerator kpg = Mockito.mock(KeyPairGenerator.class);
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(KeyPairGenerator.class);
        when(KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_PAIR_ALGORITHM, DEFAULT_PROVIDER)).thenReturn(kpg);
    }
}
```

I've tried replacing `when(KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_PAIR_ALGORITHM, DEFAULT_PROVIDER)).thenReturn(kpg);` with `PowerMockito.doReturn(kpg).when(KeyPairGenerator.class);` but neither seem to get me where I want as I'm still getting the NoSuchProviderException. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This exception is thrown when a particular security provider is requested but is not available in the environment. Will you please debug the code and tell at which line you get this error and add full stack-trace of the error. waiting..

Comment: Could you add class under test into prepareForTest section? It helps sometime

Comment: The system under test is a custom class that calls "final KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KEY_PAIR_ALGORITHM, DEFAULT_PROVIDER);" And this is the line that generates the exception. I realize the exception is occurring because the security provider is not available, that's why I've attempted to mock this call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want try changing your line @PrepareForTest statement.

From:

```java
@PrepareForTest(KeyPairGenerator.class)
```

to:

```java
@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCallsTheStaticMethod.class)
```

Comment: Can you add reference to any documentation which mentions this. I see people countering it as well, that it is not correct to add the outer class. And `KeyPairGenerator.class` itself must be in `PrepareForTest` . 
There is 0% coverage as well when you add the class to test in most cases.