# Unable to stub a static method call using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I have a file `Util.java`:

```
public class Util  {
    public static int returnInt() {
        return 1;
    }

    public static String returnString() {
        return "string";
    }
}
```

Another class:

```
public class ClassToTest {
    public String methodToTest() {
        return Util.returnString();
    }
}
```

I want to test it using TestNg and PowerMockito:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)
public class PharmacyConstantsTest {    
    ClassToTest classToTestSpy;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        classToTestSpy = spy(new ClassToTest());
    }

    @Test
    public void method() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Util.class);
        when(Util.returnString()).thenReturn("xyz");
        classToTestSpy.methodToTest();
    }
}
```

However, it throws the following error:

> FAILED: method
>   org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
>   when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
>   For example:
>       when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

I tried this solution using various solutions from the web, but could not locate the mistake in my code. I need to stub the call for static method, since I need it for a legacy code.
[How do I mock a static method using PowerMockito?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14289056/how-do-i-mock-a-static-method-using-powermockito)

Comment: I've tried these as well. None worked:
1. `PowerMockito.when(Util.class, MemberMatcher.method(Util.class, "returnString")).withNoArguments().thenReturn("xyz");`
2. `PowerMockito.doReturn("xyz").when(Util.class,"returnString");`
3. `doReturn("xyz").when(Util.class);
   Util.returnString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the record, adding making the test class a subclass of `PowerMockTestCase` worked for me.

```
@PrepareForTest(Util.class)
public class PharmacyConstantsTest extends PowerMockTestCase {    
    ClassToTest classToTestSpy;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        classToTestSpy = spy(new ClassToTest());
    }

    @Test
    public void method() throws Exception {
        mockStatic(Util.class);
        when(Util.returnString()).thenReturn("xyz");
        classToTestSpy.methodToTest();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure TestNG to use the PowerMock object factory like this:

```
<suite name="dgf" verbose="10" object-factory="org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory">
    <test name="dgf">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.mycompany.Test1"/>
            <class name="com.mycompany.Test2"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

in your suite.xml file of the project.

Please refer this [link](http://www.jayway.com/2009/12/14/powermock-testng-true/).

Comment: I don't already have a `suite.xml` in my project. But I do have a `testng.xml` file which contains some content. So should a create a `suite.xml`, if yes, what should be its path?

Comment: Yes, in that same `testng.xml` file, you need to specify the class you want to test using **org.powermock.modules.testng.PowerMockObjectFactory**. Anyway, I see you have found out how to do it programmatically.

Comment: Without the `extends PowerMockTestCase`, the above solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Use [PowerMockito](http://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-api-mockito/1.6.4/org/powermock/api/mockito/PowerMockito.html) methods instead of the Mockito's. The docs states that:

> PowerMockito extends Mockito functionality with several new features such as mocking static and private methods and more. Use PowerMock instead of Mockito where applicable.

Per instance:

```
PowerMockito.when(Util.returnString()).thenReturn("xyz");
```

Comment: I changed the test method with the following. It still shows the same error:                                                                                                                 @Test
  public void method()  {
   
   PowerMockito.mockStatic(Util.class);
   PowerMockito.when(Util.returnString()).thenReturn("xyz");
   classToTestSpy.methodToTest();
  }

Comment: PowerMockito's when is just a delegate to Mockito.when.